# How to know if touch position is in a specific area - Android

Tags: android, position, touch

I want to call a method if a specific area of screen (my `RelativeLayout`) has been tapped. I'm devveloping a **tic-toc-toe** game, I want to make the `alpha` value of every  circle or cross in each tapped square.
here is my `xml` file, every `ImageView` will become a circle or cross if became tapped:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#e4f7a6"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonRed"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:src="@drawable/board"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/red"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/leftCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:translationX="20dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rightCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:translationX="-20dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/upCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:translationY="40dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/upLeft"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:translationX="20dp"
        android:translationY="40dp"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/upRight"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:translationY="40dp"
        android:translationX="-20dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/downLeft"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:translationY="-40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:translationX="20dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/downRight"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:translationY="-40dp"
        android:translationX="-20dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/downCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="-40dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know how to get tapped point position with:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    return true;
}
```

So how should I get area of each square in **tic toc toe** board?

Comment: you have to define one method that obtain a center  point of your image

Comment: @NitinMakwana how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply on focus change listner to the imageview and do your code where the image view will get the focus like:-

```
if(hasFocus){
// do your code

}else{

}
```

Comment: do you mean for each imageview I should write a method and change the alpha and resource ?

Comment: @ShahriarMJ apply on focus change listner to the your's imageview and do what ever you want to do ! when the imageview gets focus it runs your code and don't forget to remove focus when the image view does not get the focus.